# Trash works on NTFS when mounted by Nautilus, but not when automounted via /etc/fstab

Tags: nautilus, automount, fstab, trash

I have 2 "data" drives.  One is **ntfs**, the other is **ext4**.

The Trash works for both drives when I allow Nautilus to handle the mount.

I've opted to auto-mount them via entries in /etc/fstab, but when I do this, only the **ext4** gives me a functioning Trash directory.

Trash on the **ntfs** drive simply does not work.
When I press "delete" or use the context menu item "Move to Trash", I get this error dialog message.

`Cannot move file to trash, do you want to delete immediately?`
`. . . .    The file "test" cannot be moved to the trash . . . .`

Here are my /etc/fstab lines.

```
/dev/sdb1 /media/D_0931_data   ntfs  defaults  0   0  
/dev/sdc1 /media/E_0298_back   ext4  defaults  0   0
```

... and here is how I created the mountpoint directories.

```
sudo mkdir  /media/D_0931_data  
sudo mkdir  /media/E_0298_back
```

Everything seems to be working fine, except for the Trash on the **ntfs** drive...
The Trash on the **ext4** drive works normally.

**UPDATE:**  more info about ownership change after `sudo mount -a`

```
sudo mkdir  /media/D_0931_data
sudo mkdir  /media/E_0298_back
#
ls -la      /media
  drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 2010-11-28 10:27 D_0931_data
  drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 2010-11-28 10:27 E_0298_back
#
gksu gedit  /etc/fstab
  /dev/sdb1 /media/D_0931_data   ntfs  defaults  0   0
  /dev/sdc1 /media/E_0298_back   ext4  defaults  0   0
#
sudo mount -a
#
ls -la      /media
  drwxrwxrwx  1 root root  12288 2010-11-28 10:22 D_0931_data
  drwxrwxr-x  5 root axiom  4096 2010-11-28 09:51 E_0298_back
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe Nautilus needs a `.Trash-1000` folder in the root of the filesystem (e.g. `/media/D_0931_data/.Trash-1000`) to exist and be user-writeable.

**NOTE**: the `1000` in the `.Trash-1000` is your user ID. You can get yours by `id -u USERNAME`. Change it accordingly if needed.

Try running this: `sudo mkdir /media/D_0931_data/.Trash-1000; sudo chmod 777 /media/D_0931_data/.Trash-1000`.

If that didn't work, can you try the same but with `.Trash` instead of `Trash-1000`, and if *that* didn't work, post the output of `ls -la /media/D_0931_data`?

Try adding this to fstab (on the ntfs line): `defaults,uid=1000` instead of just `defaults`.

Comment: I approximately followed what you've said.. and the most significant(?) thing I've seen is that the ownership and permission of the the mountpoint folders change after `sudo mount -a` ... I don't know how to interpret this... (I've added the steps to my question)... Re the .Trash directory, I couldn't change permissions (strange!)

Comment: I assume that the permissions change because of my "default" entry in /etc/fstab ... but ntfs is quite **different** to ext4.

Comment: Ah, of course, there are no permissions on `ntfs`. Silly me.

Comment: Can you post the output of ls -la `/media/D_0931_data`?

Comment: Try adding this to fstab: `ntfs defaults,uid=1000` instead of just `defaults`.

Comment: evgeny: Marvleous! You've saved the day! .... it works now (with uid=1000) ... Thanks.

Comment: adding this to fstab partition line solved the problem `ntfs-3g  defaults,umask=077,uid=1000,gid=100,users,exec,noauto,noatime 0 0`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is a bit of a bug in nautilus, maybe you could report it? I've experienced this as well and as far as I understand it is one of those silly "features" of nautilus, where it does something in a way it really should not by logic.

It seems to be related to the way nautilus "understands" the automounted drive; it sees it as being non-native somehow and disables some features (a safety "feature"). As I said earlier, the best option here is to report a bug on nautilus.

Comment: It seems that Nautilus handles the Trash perfectly well when it mounts the ntfs drive, by me clicking on the drive "label" in **Places**..  I've been assuming that Nautilus would not be involved at all if I auto-mount via /etc/fstab, but I "think" that perhaps Nautilus is the app which actually manages the Trash... If that is the case, then there could well be some odd interaction.. I'll have to look at it a bit more later.. this is spinning me out (need a break).. If I pinpoint that it is not something I've done incorrectly, I'll try to report a bug, but is it Bugzilla or Launchpad or...??

Comment: better bugzilla since it could be dealt with upstream at once, but if you want a faster/more friendly response launchpad is generally better (though there is the risk upstream would deny any patches simply because they come from Canonical).